# Word for "pain gets worse"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

> "The pain kept increasing."

I was looking for a substitute of "increasing" that expresses the idea that pain didn't subside and instead intensified.

I have overused these words (*increasing*, *worsening*, *getting worse*, *intensifying*...); so, I'm looking for some other words to capture the expression.

Answer (score 3):

Try *growing, spreading*, or phrases that have the format ***becoming/growing [more] + ADJ.***

The latter strategy will enable you to expand the possible range of descriptions with adjectives like *unbearable, excruciating, agonizing, tormenting,* and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

> The pain kept [*creeping up*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/creep).

Comment: Strangely that crept up from another answer...

Answer (score 1):

*Exacerbated* is a good word to describe an increase in the intensity of pain (or more generally, any unpleasant sensation).

E.g. of usage: "Rather than helping to alleviate the pain of my wound, the drug actually exacerbated it!"

Comment: That usage would require something to change the level of pain. If the pain increased or worsened on its own, it cannot be exacerbated.

Comment: @MarchHo It's true that "exacerbate" implies a causal agent. If you don't want this implication, then *intensified* would be a more generic substitute. But the OP has already excluded this from consideration.